# Python socket - An invalid argument was supplied

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, invalid-argument, argument-error

I have a problem with a python server I am creating. It works on my home machine, but when I've tried to run it on a different machine it does not work. When compiled using pyinstaller, the window immideatly closes, and when ran as a raw python file (python 2.7.10 is installed on both my home machine and the machine it is not working on) it throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fileModifyServer.py", line 136, in <module>
    startServer()
File "fileModifyServer.py", line 11, in startServer
  serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
File "N:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 191, in __init__
  _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

My code it is referencing to is as follows:

```
import socket

def startServer():
    global serversocket

    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8010))
    serversocket.listen(5)
    print "Server started"
```

Comment: Like I said it works on my home machine but not on this machine, so you may not be able to reproduce it, because it seems to be a machine specific problem.

Comment: It does not have the PF_INET attribute

Comment: try a different port than 8010?

Comment: Changing the port does not help

Comment: Anyone else got ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The traceback you have is strange. It indicates a line when attempting to instantiate the socket, which would indicate a problem with your python installation or network stack. It also indicates that error occurred on line 11, but in your code the line in question appears on line 6. I'm not sure how it happened here, but I know this can happen if you edit files while your program is running and then it crashes. The traceback simply prints out the line number from the file in question that caused the error, and the file source doesn't appear to be read until the error occurs; Therefore the traceback will reflect the line in the modified file, which isn't the line that was present when the program was compiled, and thus is not the line that actually caused the problem.

Without looking at the traceback, I do see an error with your code. You are attempting to bind your server to an invalid interface. The hostname returned by socket.gethostname is not an interface. [From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname):

```
If you want to know the current machine’s IP address, you may want to use gethostbyname(gethostname()). 
This operation assumes that there is a valid address-to-host mapping for the host, and the assumption does not always hold.

# for example
local_ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Which will return a string representation of your local ip address. Unfortunately, that would still throw an error, as it is not an interface that you can bind to.

Some interfaces that you can bind to include "0.0.0.0", which means all available interfaces, and "localhost", which means "local" connections only, so no external network traffic allowed.